# Components in Tailwind v4 alpha

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How do i create a component (e.g. container, btn) in Tailwind v4 alpha. Not sure if you can but i cant figure out how to

```css
@theme {
  .container {
    --padding: var(--spacing-4);
  }
}
```

No luck here, error says only properties and @keyframes can exist within theme so not sure what to do